# How to lock user account after multiple attempted and password must not be plain text in Oracle Apex?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I got a user table with column email, password, is_locked(varchar2(1) default = 'N'), login_failed(number default = 0). Below is the code which I write for my custom authentication scheme:

```
FUNCTION my_user_auth(
    p_username in varchar2,
    p_password in varchar2)
    RETURN boolean
IS
    l_result NUMBER := 0;
    l_locked VARCHAR2(1) := 'N';
    Sts NUMBER := 0;
    v_return BOOLEAN := FALSE;
BEGIN
    SELECT 1, USER_TYPE_ID, IS_LOCKED INTO l_result, Sts, l_locked
      FROM USER_INFO 
      WHERE LOWER(EMAIL) = LOWER(p_username)
      AND LOGIN_PASSWORD = p_password;

    if (l_locked ='N' AND l_result = 1) then
        APEX_UTIL.SET_SESSION_STATE('GLOBAL_STATUS_ITEM', Sts);
        v_return := TRUE;
    elsif (l_locked ='Y') then 
        apex_util.set_custom_auth_status (p_status => 'Account Locked, Exceeded Maximum Attempts! Please contact support staff.');
        v_return := false;
    end if;

RETURN v_return;

END my_user_auth;
```

Is that possible to make the user's email locked (change "is_locked" value to 'Y') after several failed attempt on login?

I had tried to add the code below but after added the code the user can't even login to the system even the password is correct:

```
if(l_result = 0) then
    if(login_failed > 3) then
        UPDATE USER_INFO
        SET is_locked = 'Y'
        WHERE email = p_username;
    elsif
        UPDATE USER_INFO
        SET login_failed = login_failed + 1
        WHERE email = p_username;
    endif;
endif;
```

In addition, I got a form based on table which allow user to update their password, how can I set a constraint to make sure that the password insert is not plain text, e.g. included uppercase, special character and etc.

Thank you.

Comment: Any reason for custom authentication? The features your request are available out of the box with APEX authentication, and you don't need to worry about hashing your own passwords https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.1/aeadm/configuring-security.html

Comment: Because I dont have the full access control and got some restriction to set up some policy for the applicaiton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using JavaScript/Oracle Function. If you prefer to use JavaScript, i hope the below script helps you to achieve it assuming P1_PASSWORD is the variable the gets the input,add the below script on change (dynamic action).

```
var hasUpperCase = /[A-Z]/.test($v("P1_PASSWORD"));
var hasLowerCase = /[a-z]/.test($v("P1_PASSWORD"));
var hasNumbers = /\d/.test($v("P1_PASSWORD"));
var hasNonalphas = /\W/.test($v("P1_PASSWORD"));
if (hasUpperCase + hasLowerCase + hasNumbers + hasNonalphas < 3 || $v("P1_PASSWORD").length < 8 )
{
apex.message.clearErrors();
apex.message.showErrors([
  {
    type: apex.message.TYPE.ERROR,
    location: ["inline"],
    pageItem: "P1_PASSWORD",
    message: "Password should contain Uppercase,lowercase,number and Special character greater than 8 characters",
    unsafe: false
  }
]);
 }
```

For Oracle Function, you can refer to the Oracle Function available in the `$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin/utlpwdmg.sql` location. Modify the function and create it as per your needs and you can use it for validation. 
Hope this helps you.